# trying to create a fill in the blank quiz in python

Tags: python-3.x

I have to make a fill in the blank quiz for my online class but I seem to be stuck, and am having trouble finding out *why* I'm stuck. Any advice would be great, thanks! this is my code so far... When I run the code it gets to the point of asking the first question and is looking for an answer but when I put it in it gives me the "not quite, please try again" prompt so am I not calling the answers right?

```
print ('Welcome to my computer programming Quiz, in this quiz you will be 
asked to select from three difficulty levels, easy, medium, and hard. Each 
the level contains 4 - 5 fill in the blank questions')
print ('')
print ('Your score at the end will be based on how many correct answers you 
get compared to the number of guesses you take')
print ('')
# opening introduction to the Quiz

level=None
while level not in ['easy', 'medium', 'hard']:
    level = input ('Please select a difficulty (easy, medium, or hard):').lower() 
    # This is where the difficulty is chosen, this is also is the reason I couldn't get my 
    # code to open until I did some searching around the internet and found that 
    # raw_input had to be replaced with input in newer versions of python. Also, I found 
    # that adding .lower() makes the user's input lower case so that it fits with the 
    # potential answers.

guesses, score = 0, 0 
# this is where the number of guesses and the number of right answers will be collected 
# and then shown to the user at the end

easy_questions = ['When you give a computer an instruction, its called 
giving a computer a _____.',
         'The _____ of a computer language is the set of rules that 
defines the combination of symbols that are considered to be a correctly 
structured document or fragment in that language.',
         'A _____ is a value, one that can change based on conditions.',
         'One piece of a larger group is called a _____ in computer 
programming.',
         '_____ are made up of elements, and are enclosed in square brackets.']

medium_questions = ['A _____ starts with the keyword def followed by the its name.',
         'A _____ is a character that represents an action, such as x representing multiplication.',
         'A _____ is a set of coded instructions that tell a computer how to run a program or calculation.',
         'A _____ is traditionally a sequence of characters either as a literal constant or as some kind of variables.',
         'An expression inside brackets is called the _____ and must be an integer value.']

hard_questions = ['A sequence of instructions that is continually repeated until a certain condition is reached, is called a _____ function.',
         'A control flow statement that allows code to be executed repeatedly based on a true/false statement is called a _____ loop.',
         'This is a common thing in programming when a variable is defined and then redefined the variable has gone through a _____.',
         '_____ refers to the situation where the same memory location can be accessed using different names']

# The first thing I tried was having all the questions and then all of the answers 
# together in two big lists bc of some code I saw online while researching how to 
# do this project but couldn't figure out how to make that code work so I started 
# over and tried this way with longer code but code I thought I could make work.

easy_answers = ['command', 'syntax', 'variable', 'element', 'lists']

medium_answers = ['function', 'operator', 'procedure', 'string', 'index']

hard_answers = ['loop', 'while', 'mutation', 'aliasing']

if level == 'easy':
    questions = easy_questions
    answers = easy_answers

elif level == 'medium':
    questions = medium_questions
    answers = medium_answers

elif level == 'hard':
    questions = hard_questions
    answers = hard_answers
    # this is how I bet thought to get the the right questions and answers to be called up.

number_of_questions = 5
question_number = 0

def check_answer(user_answer, questions, answers):

    if user_answer == answers:
        print ('')
        print ('Correct!')
        score = + 1
        guesses = + 1
        question_number =  + 1
        # this will increase the score and guesses by one and move the quiz on to 
        # the next question.
    else:
        print ('')
        print ('Not quite, please try again')
        guesses = + 1
        # this will only increase the guesses by one, and give the user another 
        # chance to answer the same question again.

while question_number < number_of_questions:
    questions = questions[question_number]
    user_answer = answers[question_number]
    print('')
    user_answer = input (questions + ': ').lower() 
    # Prompts the user to answer the fill in the blank question.

    print (check_answer(user_answer, questions, answers))
    # this is where im also having a lot of trouble, ive done some research online and this
    # is what i was told to use but it doesn't seem to be working.

    print ('')
    print ('Congratulations, you have completed the ' + str(level) + ' level, with a score of ' + str(score) + ' out of ' + str(guesses) + ' guesses')
```

Comment: Please read, which [questions are considered on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Especially #1 is relevant here. And [this blog post](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) gives good advice, how to debug programs. You can test small parts of the program also on [PythonTutor](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit) and observe, what happens to each variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the problem seems to be very trivial. When you check if the `answer` is correct or not in the `check_answer` with the code line below:

```
if user_answer == answers:
```

you're `answers` is an `array` containing all the answers while the `user_answer` is the string that the user has typed. Hence, when you type the first answer as "command" is tries to match the string "command" to an `array` containing a few strings. which is definitely not gonna match.

use the below code line to solve it:

```
if user_answer in answers:
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot of sense now that i see it. would i do something similar to that to make the next question call up. bc it said correct and then nothing

Comment: What I would suggest is that your code isn't quite well. you'll have a tough time maintaining it or even rather adding more questions

Comment: So should I start over? Are the questions not in a way that i can call them? or is it my while loops? thanks for your help I'm sorta beating my head against my desk

Comment: Ok, that would be great but stackoverflow is asking me to wait 1 day before i ask another question so i will ask it tmrw if you are still available. I will reply the link tmrw, thanks again

Comment: yeah sure. i'll write up the script eitherways